# How can I get new characters ready on bloodborne faster?

Tags: bloodborne

I'm a huge fan of bloodborne, but there's one feature that is in Dark Souls 2 and Dark Souls 3 missing in it. Resetting your stats and reallocating points. I just want to be able to try out some new builds but it's just **so hard** to progress through the game on certain builds (arcane for example).

It takes me ages to progress through bloodborne anyway and I really want to try an arcane build. I just can't progress through the game with one. It's really difficult and time consuming.

Is there any way to just load in a character on bloodborne? How can I make the game easier for myself to minimise the *stupid* amount of time it takes to make a build for one weapon?

I want to make a build using the beast cutter but I know I'll have to invest another 20 hours on a new character just to have the stats for it.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no such feature available in Bloodborne. The only way to get the levels you need, is to grind.

The good news is, YouTube is full of quick and easy guides on good places to grind, to get mass Blood Echoes in a short amount of time, like [this one](https://youtu.be/Pnxa1RWqrvg).

As for why this isn't in the game yet, well, like in Dark Souls 1, if they added such a feature, you would miss out on the experience of playing as different builds. Switching between builds is nice, but it bypasses the experience of the game. Perhaps we might see it in later games.